# how to keep text formatting when paste from react quill text editor

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, text, react-quill

I'm using React quill (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-quill) in a SaaS so users can edit and format text as they want (titles, bold, italic etc).

My question is : is there a way to keep text formatting when copy paste FROM the rich text editor to, let's say, google doc or word documents ?

It doesn't work right now but I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you copy and paste content from a rich text editor like React Quill to other applications like Google Docs or Microsoft Word, the formatting is usually lost. This is because different applications use different formatting styles and markup languages.

However, you can enable the copy-paste functionality with formatting preservation by implementing custom handling for the copy and paste events in React Quill. Here's how you can achieve that:

1. Install the `html-to-text` library by running the following command in your project directory:

```bash
npm install html-to-text
```

2. Import the necessary dependencies in your React component:

```js
import ReactQuill from 'react-quill';
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css';
import htmlToText from 'html-to-text';
```

3. Create a custom function to handle the paste event and convert the pasted HTML to plain text:

```js
const handlePaste = (e) => {
  const clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
  const pastedData = clipboardData.getData('text/html');
  const plainText = htmlToText.fromString(pastedData);

  // Do something with the plain text, if needed

  // Prevent Quill's default paste handling
  e.preventDefault();
};
```

4. Pass the `handlePaste` function as a prop to the React Quill component:

```js
<ReactQuill
  // other props
  onPaste={handlePaste}
/>
```

By implementing this approach, you can intercept the paste event, convert the pasted HTML to plain text using the `html-to-text` library, and perform any required processing or manipulation before applying it to your rich text editor.

Please note that this method converts the pasted HTML to plain text, so the formatting won't be preserved when pasting into applications like Google Docs or Microsoft Word. However, it allows you to work with the extracted plain text for further customization or processing as per your requirements.

Comment: onPaste would be if I needed exterior data to be pasted in Quill right ? It's the opposite I need.
Actually I just realized the paste formatting (outside of the app) is working in software like openOffice but doesn't work in Google doc. Is there something specific with it ?

Comment: I found something weird. Tried a Quill app example (here : https://codesandbox.io/s/devmnj-quilljs-editor-react-example-ogk0im?file=/src/App.js) and copy paste works great.
Now from my app, only the bold text actually doesn't work for any reason.